# HTML Support for Experience Editor Info Notifications

Tags: experience-editor

I'm trying to add simple html such as bullets, underline, bold inside an Custom Experience Editor Notification.

I have followed the example outlined by Marek Below (and looked at many other examples too):

[How to provide custom info messages in Sitecore Preview Mode](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10864/how-to-provide-custom-info-messages-in-sitecore-preview-mode)

My custom GetPageEditorNotificationsProcessor pipeline is firing and adding my custom messages and my custom WebEditRibbonForm class is loading when I attach a breakpoint to the OnLoad() method. My RenderNotification() method (which contains my changes) runs and I can see my changes reflected on this line in the RenderNotifications() method:

```
 this.Notifications.InnerHtml = output.InnerWriter.ToString();
```

However when I look on the front-end in experience editor my changes are not present. All the text and html set in my custom WebEditRibbonForm class just doesn't show up. The html I try and set from my custom GetPageEditorNotificationsProcessor pipeline is there but it is rendered as text (as seen below). I want to show this as html so that is why I've trying to over-ride the WebEditRibbonForm method to handle this.

[image]

I can see that PageEditorNotificationOption items are rendered as links so it is possible to support html somehow but It's not working for me.

One other thing I noticed is that the markup for the message is like so:

```
<div class="sc-messageBar-messageText-container">
```

Yet this doesn't match up with the markup in my pipeline which is like so:

```
<div class="scPageEditorNotification">
```

This suggest that perhaps some js such as that in MessageBar.js and the knockout view of MessageBar.cshtml is being used instead (as that markup matches) but when I try and edit these files I am seeing no changes in Experience Editor either. Very confusing.

**Further info:** Sitecore 8.2 update 7

Comment: Which Sitecore version?

Comment: Sorry forgot to say 8.2 u7

Comment: In `Sitecore.Speak.Components.Web.dll` there is `_sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_version_2_Layouts_Renderings_Common_MessageBars_MessageBar_cshtml` class which renders output of `MessageBar` html. In theory it should be enough to replace `text` binding with `html` binding in line containing `data-bind="text: viewModel.Text()` but I wasn't able to find how you can replace Sitecore implementation with custom one. I thought it's the `/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Common/MessageBar` item from `core` database, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Marek, I’m not going mad then . I wonder if anyone else had done this and knows how to solve this issue.

Comment: So because Marek is right - I won't steal his wind :) The only thing that is wrong is that this one is actually using the verison 1 of speak and not version 2 - so the control is located in `/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 1/Layouts/Renderings/Common/MessageBar` and you have to change the text: to html binding in the file located on this path - '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/Layouts/Renderings/Common/MessageBars/MessageBar.cshtml'

Comment: Forgot to mention that speak is heavily cached, so just create a new .cshtml everytime you are testing (i.e. duplicate this one and change the path) And proof it is working - https://www.screencast.com/t/rlDkWp2u :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we combine what [@nsgocev](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/127/nsgocev) wrote in his comment and what I wrote in mine, we have the following answer:

- create a duplicate of `/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/Layouts/Renderings/Common/MessageBars/MessageBar.cshtml` file and change the `text:` binding to `html:` binding in every line containing `data-bind="text: text, attr: { title: text }"`
- find the `/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 1/Layouts/Renderings/Common/MessageBar`
- update the path field to the path of the duplicated file
  [image]
- as Speak is heavily cached, always create a copy of cshtml file and update the path, otherwise it may not work
- and proof that it's working (thanks to  [@nsgocev](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/127/nsgocev)): https://www.screencast.com/t/rlDkWp2u

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @nsgocev and Marek. I'll give this a go but it looks like this should solve the issue :-)